# Can I build a 3-phase transformer bank out of single transformers of different KVAs?

Tags: power-supply, transformer

Can I build a 3-phase transformer bank out of single transformers of different kVAs?

Can I build a 3 phase transformer bank with 2 transformers of additive polarity and 1 of substractive polarity?

The connection is Dy7, 2 transformers of 100kVA additive polarity and 1 transformer of 50kVA substractive polarity

Comment: It depends on whether you want delta or star, the ratings, the load, etc., but you have provided no details. You would need to provide a schematic for the "subtractive polarity" scheme. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar and it has transformer components. Note that 'KVA' is kelvin-volt-amperes. Use 'kVA' for transformer specifications. Capitals matter.

Comment: You could but then it will not perfect as well as normal . Mutual coupling is important for balanced load regulation

Comment: The connection is Dy7. Two transformers are 100kVA additive polarity and the other is 50kVA substractive polarity

Comment: This sounds familiar and also looks like a school question.  There is an effort requirement for those, so you might want to do a little rambling about what you think will happen.  Subtractive polarity and additive polarity just indicate the connection direction of the output windings.  Reversing the direction flips the sine wave upside down.  So look at a graph of 3 phase sine waves.  Is it OK to flip one of them upside down?  What happens?  As far as mismatching transformer sizes, I took electrician courses so for us that's covered by code, but you probably want theory.

Comment: Good luck balancing the load… not perfect but would somewhat work. Also it smells homeworks:P